VBA: How to Loop IF Statement through a Cell and Chart Series
Currently I have:
    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart").Activate
    Dim ch As Chart
    Set ch = ActiveChart
    If Range("D4").Value = 0 Then
    ch.SeriesCollection("Series1").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    ElseIf Range("D4").Value > 2 Then
    ch.SeriesCollection("Series1").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    ElseIf Range("D4").Value <= 2 And Range("D4").Value >= 1 Then
    ch.SeriesCollection("Series1").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 200, 0)
    ElseIf Range("D4").Value < -2 Then
    ch.SeriesCollection("Series1").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf Range("D4").Value < 0 And Range("D4").Value >= -1 Then
    ch.SeriesCollection("Series1").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(200, 0, 0)
    Else
    ch.SeriesCollection("Series1").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
    End Sub

Which looks at a value in D4 and if D4 is between my bounds, it assigns the chart series a certain color (this value is not on the chart but rather an indicator used to classify the charts movement).
I want to loop this through 10 different Chart Series Collections, where in each Loop, I go down one cell. so go to Cell D5 check all conditions for Series 2, then Cell D6, check all conditions for Series 3
I am stuck here as I know how to do this for one half of this, but unsure how to loop into chartseries
Error I get:


Full code is exactly yours

Considering your comment, it can be a solution:
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
  Dim i As Integer
  Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D10")
  For i = 1 To 7
    ProcessSeries i, rng.Cells(i).Value
  Next
End Sub

Sub ProcessSeries(i As Integer, j As Double)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart") _
      .SeriesCollection("Series" & i).Format.Line.ForeColor
        If j < -2 Then
            .RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' for values up to -2
        ElseIf j < -1 Then
            .RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' for values from -2 to -1
        ElseIf j < 0 Then
            .RGB = RGB(200, 0, 0) ' for values from -1 to 0
        ElseIf j = 0 Then
            .RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' for value of 0
        ElseIf j < 1
            .RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' for values from 0 to 1
        ElseIf j <= 2 Then
            .RGB = RGB(0, 200, 0) ' for values from 1 to 2
        Else
            .RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' for values above 2
        End If
    End With
End Sub

In Worksheet_Calculate, ProcessSeries is called for every "i" from 1 to 7. "i" and the value of related cell among "D4:D10" are provided for ProcessSeries.
When ProcessSeries starts, it has "i" as the number of the data series (we expect series are named like "Series1".."Series7" what is done automatically when the chart is created). "j" gives the number from the related cell of "D4:D10".

thank you! one question, I am try to run the worksheet_calculate on a seperate sheet (so as to force it to only occur only when this list of values is updated via a formula)
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart").Activate
With Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = .Range("D4:D10")
End With
For i = 1 To 7
ProcessSeries i, rng.Cells(i).Value
Next
End Sub
this says "By Ref Arguement Type Mismatch".. any ideas?

I guess you need to check if Range("D4:D10") contains integer numbers only.

thank you- is there anyway around this? as these figures may often look like -1.4333

Sure, just I concerned on integers, which isn't correct. Modified the code: Sub ProcessSeries(i As Integer, j As Double)

Thank you- would you mind taking me through how this is actually working? I am new to VBA and logically, it looks like it’s assigning each series and cell an identifier and using those to calc each time?

do you put this all in sheet 2 module? or sub in main module?

Worksheet_Calculate should be located in its module, ProcessSeries can be located in any module (better together with 'Worksheet_Calculate' or in a project module), the `Public" access modifier can be added if necessary.

Still having issues running this here- when I run it, in d4:d10 i have numerics however, debug.print i, range().cells(i).value, returns 0 as the type as the error thrown is "Type mismatch". Any ideas? Keep getting stuck here

Pls. modify your question and depict Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4:D10"). Also provide your complete code.

sure just did that now

Got it! Added Dim i As Integer, look above. Further, always provide error messages as you did it. All required information is depicted.
